# Creating a 2D table of chars with unique characters in every line and column

Tags: java, arrays, char

I am trying to make a 2D table in which characters cannot repeat in column or line. I am trying to do at least 2 lines of arrays. I can do the first one, but I have a problem with other lines. On second line it throws an error - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  -11. Can someone help me?

Main class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

char[][] table = new char[26][26];
Random r;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
    new GlobalVars();
}

public Main() {
    r = new Random();
    createFirstLine();
    createOtherLine(1);
}

public void createFirstLine() {
    ArrayList<Integer> intLeft = GlobalVars.cIntToArrL();

    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = intLeft.size(); i > 0; i--) {
        int charPosChosen = r.nextInt(intLeft.size());
        int charPosGot = intLeft.get(charPosChosen);

        table[0][counter] = GlobalVars.getCharValue(charPosGot);
        counter ++;
        intLeft.remove(charPosChosen);
    }

    System.out.println(table[0]);
}

public void createOtherLine(int n) {
    ArrayList<Integer> intLeft = GlobalVars.cIntToArrL();
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> intLeftForCell = intLeft;
        for(int column = 0; column < n; column ++) {
            intLeftForCell.remove(
                    GlobalVars.getNumericValue(table[n][i])
                    );
        }
        int charPosChosen = r.nextInt(intLeftForCell.size());
        int charPosGot = intLeftForCell.get(charPosChosen);

        table[1][i] = GlobalVars.getCharValue(charPosGot);
        intLeft.remove((Integer)charPosGot);
    }
    System.out.println(table[1]);
}
}
```

The GlobalVars class :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GlobalVars {

public static String alphStr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
public static char[] alphArr;
public static int[] intArr = new int[26];

public GlobalVars() {
    // Changing alphabet String to alphabet Array
    alphArr = alphStr.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        intArr[i] = i;
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> cIntToArrL() {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    return list;
}

public static int getNumericValue(char c) {
    return Character.getNumericValue(c) - 10;
}

public static char getCharValue(int i) {
    return Character.forDigit(i + 10, i + 11);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got kind of lost in your code. If I understand what you want to accomplish correctly, you want to randomly generate 2D (square) array where in every row and column is every char exactly once(not duplicate and not missing from alphabet). Is that right? If yes here is my approach how to tackle this problem:

1. Create pattern from alphabet (with that unique chars rule)
2. Shuffle all rows (randomly, possibly using seed)
3. Shuffle all columns (randomly, possibly using seed)

**Step 1 - create table:**

```
char alphabet[] = {'a','b','c', ...}; // Set of chars that will be used in table
char table[][] = new char[26][26]; // Size must be same as size of alphabet

private void prepareTable() {
    for (int x = 0; x < table.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < table[x].length; y++) {
            // Copy alphabet to row in table but offset it each row by 1
            table[x][y] = alphabet[(x + y) % alphabet.length];
        }
    }
    // Now table looks like this:
    // 'a' 'b' 'c'
    // 'b' 'c' 'a'
    // 'c' 'a' 'b
}
```

**Step 2 - shuffle rows:**
For actual shuffling I am using [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

```
Random r = new Random( /* seed */ );
void shuffleRows() {
    int items = table.length;

    while (items > 0) { // While there is something to shuffle
        int index = r.nextInt(items);

        // Simple swap
        char[] tmp = table[index];
        table[index] = table[items - 1];
        table[items - 1] = tmp;

        items --; // Move on to the next
    }
}
```

**Step 3 - shuffle columns:**

```
void shuffleColumns() {
    int items = table[0].length;

    while (items > 0) {
        int index = r.nextInt(items);

        // Swap chars in each row
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            char tmp = table[i][index];
            table[i][index] = table[i][items - 1];
            table[i][items - 1] = tmp;
        }

        items --;
    }
}
```

And thats it. I hope it helps.